# WPF CEFSharp ChromiumWebBrowser - Render MemoryStream

Tags: wpf, chromium, cefsharp

I need to be able to retrieve a Pdf from our web server via a call to Web API and then render the document in the ChromiumWebBrowser for CEFSharp, all within memory and not saving the file locally.

Right now I'm at the point where I get back the file in a MemoryStream, but can't seem to get any further.

Is this possible?  Any examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options, implement a `Scheme Handler` for your own custom `scheme`, e.g. `client://` or implement a `Resource Handler`

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/41/CefSharp.Example/CefSharpSchemeHandler.cs#L46

You can use the default `ResourceHandlerFactory` if your using just statically generated resources.

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/41/CefSharp.Example/CefExample.cs#L98

or implement your own `IResourceHandlerFactory`

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/41/CefSharp/DefaultResourceHandlerFactory.cs

`Scheme Handler` is more complicated, supports `async` callbacks though. Next version of `CefSharp` will include support for `async` resource handlers. (`-pre` release should be out sometime this week)