# How can I use a ResourceHandler to render a PDF file from a MemoryStream or byte array using CefSharp ChromiumWebBrowser?

Tags: .net, wpf, pdf, webview, cefsharp

I have the same use case [as is stated in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32052129/wpf-cefsharp-chromiumwebbrowser-render-memorystream). However I'm having some trouble putting the pieces from the answer together.

I have tried this code:

```
private async Task LoadPdfFromStream()
{
    if (Element != null && Element.Source != null)
    {
        if (_webView.ResourceRequestHandlerFactory == null)
        {
            _webView.ResourceRequestHandlerFactory = new ResourceRequestHandlerFactory();
        }

        var handler = _webView.ResourceRequestHandlerFactory as ResourceRequestHandlerFactory;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            var ret = handler.RegisterHandler("file:///loadfromstream", Element.Source.ToArray());
        }

        _webView.Address = "file:///loadfromstream";
    }
}
```

The `Element.Source.ToArray()` returns the byte array that contains the PDF file. However as it is right now I render the raw content of the file on the screen as pure text, instead of as HTML.

How can I load the content as a PDF, with the zoom buttons, and etc, instead of the raw content as pure text?

Comment: You can use http://cefsharp.github.io/api/83.4.x/html/M_CefSharp_WebBrowserExtensions_RegisterResourceHandler.htm to simplify your code..

Comment: @amaitland I'll use that to do some refactoring. Also, thank you for the great work with CefSharp!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more looking into it I realized that I was just missing the mime type.

```
_pdfHandler.RegisterHandler(streamUri, Element.Source.ToArray(), "application/pdf");
```

Now the PDF is rendering from the memory stream into the Web View just fine. : )